# Ошибка с ImageView

Tags: android

Написал метод сохранения изображений в память приложения. Один из входных параметров - ImageView.
В void onItemClick (AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) есть View, по которому осуществлен клик.
из него делаю ImageView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
......
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view; // вот тут то и возникает ошибка (строка 177)
// Метод добавления логотипа в память 
addLogoFile(imageView, logoName)
}
```

А вот логи:

> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.sadko.askdroid.OnlineCatalog$2.onItemClick(OnlineCatalog.java:177)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 02-10 18:29:09.267: E/AndroidRuntime(816):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Но, почему то значение imageView "errors during the evaluation" при дебаге.. Почему?

Comment: покажи больше кода и стека ошибки

Comment: Очевидно ваш view это LinearLayout

Comment: А как из LinearLayout достать ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: LinearLayout cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: просто на view поищи